# generate a mp4 file from list of images by using jcodec library

Tags: android, video-processing, jcodec

I am using JCodec library to convert a list of bitmap images into a mp4 file. Everything works fine but the generated mp4 file plays the first image correctly and the rest of the images don't get rendered properly.

here is my encoder code

```
  private class Encoder extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, Integer> {
    private static final String TAG = "ENCODER";
    protected Integer doInBackground(File... params) {
        SequenceEncoder se = null;

        Bitmap[] arrayOfBitmap = {bmp, bmpdef};


        try {
            se = new SequenceEncoder(new File(params[0].getParentFile(),
                    "jcodec_enc.mp4"));

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayBitmap.length; i++) {




                        se.encodeImage(arrayBitmap[i]);


                }

            se.finish();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO", e);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progress.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
    }
}
```

Please help me where am making the mistake

Comment: "The rest of the images" is only one image as your bmp array contains only 2 elements. In jcodec v0.2.0, there is an Android wrapper that works good. But as there is no oficial release of 0.2.0, you have to compile it your self.